# How to display the column names which have only unique non-null values in MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which I want to show the names of columns which contain unique values and aren't null. In other words I want to display the candidate keys from the table. Note that while creating the table, the UNIQUE or NOT NULL constraint may or may not have been provided for the required columns.

My thought process was to somehow check if `COUNT(DISTINCT columnn_name) = COUNT(*)' for every column in the table, and print the column names for which the condition is true. But I don't know how to write this in a query.
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: This is a homework question. The question just showed us a table and told us to identify potential candidate keys in the table using a query. The reason I want to do it dynamically/automatically is that if I do the count=count for every column and then manually see which ones it is true for, I might as well just see which columns are distinct and not null, which makes this approach seem wrong.

Comment: just do your count=count for every column in the table?  or do you mean you want to dynamically do it for all columns without knowing what they are?  you will get a better answer if you explain why you want to do this; what do you want to do with these "candidate keys"?

Comment: Yes, I would like to do it dynamically. As for 'why'- it was a homework question. The question just showed us a table and told us to identify potential candidate keys in the table using a query. The reason I want to do it dynamically is that if I do the count=count for every column and then manually see which ones it is true for, I might as well just see which columns are distinct and not null, which makes this approach seem wrong.

Comment: keys are useful many times when the value is not unique and/or sometimes null.  are you sure you mean by "candidate keys" what they mean?

Comment: have a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-columns-table.html.  re doing it dynamically, you can either form the query from that in a client in some programming language or you can do that in a query that sets a user variable and then prepare/run it (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/prepare.html). either way there is more than one query, so I don't know that counts as "identify potential candidate keys in the table using a query"

Comment: either way, if performance isn't an issue, your query looks like `select 'foo' col from a_table having count(distinct foo)=count(*) union all select 'bar' from a_table having count(distinct bar)=count(*)...`